# Transpose a raw SQL query with doctrine

Tags: php, sql, symfony, orm, doctrine

I'm pretty new to Doctrine ORM and I'm trying to transform a raw SQL query with doctrine to get an array of Entities.

Basically I want to get one of more `course` entities where a user is indirectly registered. The `course` id is in a `traineeship` table. The `traineeship` id  and the `user` id are in a `registration` table.

Here's my SQL query :

```sql
SELECT * FROM course c
LEFT JOIN traineeship t
ON c.id = t.courseId
LEFT JOIN registration r
ON t.id = r.traineeshipId
WHERE r.userId = 2681;
```

Here's what I try to do with doctrine :

```php
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->andWhere('t.course = c')
    ->leftJoin('c.traineeships', 't')
    ->andWhere('r.traineeship = t')
    ->leftJoin('t.registrations', 'r')
    ->andWhere('r.id = :user')
    ->setParameter('user', $user)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

With my raw SQL query, I get two expected results with a given id. With the generated query by doctrine, I get only one result. So I guess my doctrine use is bad.

(Doctrine relations :

Course **OneToMany** Traineeship

Traineeship **OneToMany** Registration

Registration **ManyToOne** User)

Comment: Does `$user` contain the user id or an user entity?

Comment: Regarding the left joins you do not need to add `->andWhere('t.course = c')` and `->andWhere('r.traineeship = t')`. The relationships should be defined in your entities (see https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html#association-mapping)

Comment: Please also check https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html#executing-a-query for a documentation on how to execute a query using ORM QueryBuilder

Comment: Where do you call `$this->createQueryBuilder`? Is it inside a entity repository?

Comment: @W0rma sorry for the late answer.
1. $user contains the entity, but I get the exact same result with $user->getId(). When I figured it worked with the wole entity, I left it as it (framework / orm magic).
2. Oh, interesting, thanks for the tip. I removed those lines.
3. Yup I'll read (again) the documentation and try to find how to Doctrine.
4. Yes the querybuilder is called from a custom method of the courseRepository.
Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

From the raw SQL I would expect the following query:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->leftJoin('c.traineeships', 't')
    ->leftJoin('t.registrations', 'r')
    ->andWhere('r.user = :user')
    ->setParameter('user', $user)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Please note that I'm using `->andWhere('r.user = :user')` instead of `->andWhere('r.id = :user')` as I assume that `registration.id` holds the id of the registration but not the id of the user. In my query I furthermore assume that `registration` has an attribute `user` which holds a reference to the user.

The query should return an array of course entities.